# Supervisord scheduling

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling, supervisord

Is it possible to set jobs to run every `n` days in `supervisord`, like what `cron` is doing?

I'm asking because I have different kinds of jobs, continuous / real-time and daily ones.

All my jobs are Talend jobs and I would like to have all of them in the same place, some are very long and needs to be kept alive, others are shorts and needs to run once a day.

What kind of solution should I use to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your question with the goal you want to achieve. Do you want to delete cron from your system? Why do you need to schedule them in supervisord if they don't have to be kept alive and only run every n days?

Answer (score 0):

You could use airflow(for scheduled jobs) with supervisord

Comment: There’s no rush to answer; can you provide some more detail?